# How to store values in global variables in async iterators?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, iterator

I started learning async iterators and could not figure how to store the results in global variables to use them later on.

```
let arr = [];
(async () => {
  for await (let item of items) {
    console.log(item);
    // arr.push(item)   HOW DO I PUSH THAT INSIDE?   
  }
})()
```

I declared Symbol.asyncIterator method on the object. Please check codepen https://codepen.io/INR4GE/pen/XWbVxoy?editors=1111 . Dunno why it errors on line 13, in browser it works fine. Please don't ask why am i even doing it this way. It is just for learning purposes

Comment: In the code pen you forgot the `;` between `let arr = []` and `(...)`.

Comment: fixed, but the err on line 13 is still there

Comment: No, it isn't. You may have fallen afoul of the classic "Just how do I persuade Codepen to execute my changes" problem.

Comment: Ah, yeap, the err just remained in console after i fixed, needed to refresh the pen